# Django "List" and "Detail" Views for rows with duplicate fields

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Duplicate Field rows! Duplicate Field rows!

So I have a model `Application` with a field `school_name` which can take take duplicate values, among other fields.
What I expect to achieve is: a "***list***" view of all duplicate `school name` values and their respective counts, and a "***detail***" view for each of the duplicated fields in that, when I click on a row in my 'list' view (or something of that sort), I'm able to view all the rows that contain this duplicate field, and the rest of the fields for that particular entry.

What I mean is this:

Listing the rows.
[image: Rows listed]

Then when I click on row 1(Dedan Kimathi University of Technology), or click a detail button or something of the sort for row 1, I expect to get this:

[image: Row Details]

So far I have 2 queries:

```
duplicates = Application.objects.values('school_name').annotate(name_count=Count('school_name')).filter(name_count__gt=0)
```

The query above returns the duplicate rows and their count(as in image 1), while the one below,

```
records = Application.objects.filter(school_name__in=[item['school_name'] for item in duplicates])
```

returns the other fields for the rows(as in image 2), only that it brings all the rows in the db.

What I expect is, when I click a row on the 'list', I get a 'detailed' view with the rows that have the duplicate values for the `school_name` field.

Point to note: I'm doing this on my `views.py`.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the problem. Why are you looping over all items in your second query? Why not `Application.objects.filter(school_name=selected_school_name)`?

Comment: Because I need the school name, in your case `selected_school_name` to be dynamic in that, that school name will be the name of the school in the duplicates list @DanielRoseman

Comment: So my guess is, I'll need a function that takes in a school_name as an additional parameter so that when indicating the URL for the clickable row in the duplicate list, I'll pass the school_name as an extra argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my own problem :-)
So what I did is create a function in my views that takes an extra argument, then passes that argument to the URL and to the template as follows

views.py

```
def school_detail(request, school_name):
    filtered_records = Application.objects.filter(school_name=school_name)
    context = {
        'repeated_names' : filtered_records,
        'duplicates' : duplicates,
        'title' : 'Disbursement Details',
    }

    return render(request, 'calculations/detail.html', context)
```

Then in my urls.py

```
path('list/<str:school_name>/', default_views.school_detail, name='dup_detail')
```

And finally in my template:

```
  {% for application in duplicates %}
             <tr class="clickabe-row" data-target="{% url 'dup_detail' application.school_name %}">
                <td>{{ forloop.counter}}</td>
                <td>{{ application.school_name}}</td>
                <td>{{ application.name_count}}</td>


             </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Works like a charm.